# Upgrade path for .net Membership

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I support a legacy webforms application with SQL backend and have been trying to upgrade it bit by bit
I have upgraded to .NET 4.6 (highest the hosting provider allows), added some jQuery, EF 6 goodness, refactoring in general and attempting to switch to code first from database first edmx, my next plan is to start creating new features using some kind of front end library like Vue.
But...

My problem at the moment is Membership.
It is used throughout the code and statements like

```
new Guid(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString())
```

are literally too many to bear.

And the database has 10 tables and 9 views for it.

```
vw_aspnet_Applications
vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers
vw_aspnet_Profiles
etc..
```

The application is using it for authentication and for keeping track of which user is doing what.

Is there a way to upgrade that to a modern solution without much hassle?
I can take the effort out of my own time but I'd prefer a solution that is not overkill.
the amount of users is probably less than 20 so the alternative doesn't have to be complex.
It just has to support most of what Membership is doing.

I've played with Auth0 for a bit in my own time but it seems to be not suited for this.
There is MS Identity as well but I'd prefer to take advice before going into a rabbit hole.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no simple upgrade. You will have to research identity solutions and choose one, then figure out what you need to migrate to it. Migrating identity solutions is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok - might there be a solution that's easier to implement (for example has support for Membership or can migrate from it) a bit easier than the rest?

Comment: You already asked that in your question, and I've already answered you.

Comment: To be honest the answer of: that is too broad of a question to answer on stack overflow is might be missing where to start. But thanks anyway

Comment: You could get the source (now it's all public) and port/add it (using .NET core for example) to your solution: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/Membership.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely no simple upgrade. Here's what we did in our case.

- Created ASP.NET Identity tables. We made it similar to Membershipusers table and later migrated the whole table.
- Added `ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,ApplicationUserManager , ApplicationSignInManager, ApplicationDbContext`
- Implements Autofac for DI defined at Startup.cs.
- Worked on Login/Signup Controller classes.
- Finally migrated the whole Membership DB to new aspnetusers table.

Application was initially designed using NOPCommerce (asp.net webforms) and its was relieve to replace `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()` to `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Answer (score 1):

Hassle free ? Do you mean easy path (or) scalable path ?

Design is more an opinion rather than objective. It's mostly based on the facts one know about the problem statement. Based on your's i would recommend the following.

1. Separate all the membership related code into a library (if not already done)
2. Now write interfaces that will abstract the actual authentication mechanism from the member ship related code in your project. That way your code doesn't need to be changed for any authentication related mechanism. This wouldn't also require change of database schema.
3. Now for real authentication use something like Auth0 (https://auth0.com/blog/add-auth-to-native-desktop-csharp-apps-with-jwt/) something like this will be easy to implement. But i don't know if your's is a commercial project / how the licensing will work. I know  there is a free version for auth0, but i request you to check it out.